# How to view production output of Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

Following the [docs](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#deployment) when I attempt to run the given command nothing is built.

```
$ NODE_ENV=production bundle exec rails webpacker:compile
Webpacker is installed  
Using /home/james/Documents/comity.fit/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
```

Answer (score -1):

It's working now, though I'm not sure why. I *think* all I had to do was shut down the rails server running in the background.